# Aptitude reacts very slowly when fixing unresolved issues

Tags: aptitude

When Aptitude's bottom status line permanently states

```
[1(0)/...] Resolving dependencies
```

(i.e. Aptitude can't find a solution given the current constraints), changing the status of any package (e.g. telling it to install a different version) results in a multi-second period (depending on the computer's speed) during which the screen is frozen while aptitude tries to find a new resolution.

Is there any way to convince aptitude to run its search for a solution either in the background or not at all?

Comment: For what it's worth, nothing _seeming_ to happen and nothing _happening_ are two entirely different things.  Do you experience this same delay when using `apt` or `apt-get` rather than `aptitude`?

Comment: apt and apt-get don't have interactive conflict resolution, thus I don't understand the question.

Comment: Do you see the same behavior, or is there anything more enlightening shown, if you try `aptitude -vvv`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti Keep in mind that aptitude runs as a curses application here. `aptitude -vvv` cannot show anything. That would disrupt the display.

Comment: The manual page implies that the verbosity of `-vvv` is displayed onscreen.